# How do I download libraries onto the Ubiquity Robotics Raspberry Pi image

Tags: ros, raspberry-pi, wifi, robotics-library

I downloaded an sd card image by Ubiquity Robotics which is an Ubuntu OS with ROS preinstalled onto my Raspberry Pi. This image creates a pifi access point for the Raspberry Pi and allows me to ssh into the Raspberry Pi by connecting my laptop to the access point created and doing `ssh ubuntu@10.42.0.1`. Now then I tried connecting to my home router by using `pifi add <ssid> [<password>]` and then `sudo reboot`. I was able to connect to my home router this way. So after this I tried downloading the library I needed, pygame. So i typed `sudo apt-get install python3-pygame`

And this is what i got:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package python3-pygame is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
```

So I went to a pygame site and tried downloading the library another way:

```
sudo apt install libsdl2-dev libfreetype6-dev libsdl2-mixer-dev libsdl2-image-dev libsdl2-ttf-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libportmidi-dev
```

And this is what I got:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libpng12-dev' instead of 'libpng-dev'
E: Unable to locate package libsdl2-dev
E: Unable to locate package libsdl2-mixer-dev
E: Unable to locate package libsdl2-image-dev
E: Unable to locate package libsdl2-ttf-dev
E: Unable to locate package libportmidi-dev
```

Now I have no clue on what to do and how to go about downloading the library. Is there a way I can directly download the library into the sd card image or what. Help me out pls.

Answer (score 1):

First do this

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then you try doing

`sudo apt-get install python3-pip` ?

Then do

```
sudo pip3 install pygame
```

If you are still getting the error related to SDL.

Then do this

```
sudo apt-get install libsdl2-dev
```

Comment: yeah it says `WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py" Using UNIX configuration... /bin/sh: 1: sdl-config: not found /bin/sh: 1: sdl-config: not found /bin/sh: 1: sdl-config: not found Hunting dependencies... WARNING: "sdl-config" failed! WARNING: "pkg-config freetype2" failed! Unable to run "sdl-config". Please make sure a development version of SDL is installed. ---------------------------------------- Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-bdoeu8j1/pygame/' –`

Comment: and then it said i have to upgrade pip becuz i had it in the sd card apparently and when i did it said `Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module> from pip import main ImportError: cannot import name main` –

Comment: can you please check the version of you python3 by doing this

python3 --version

Comment: Also check the version of pip3 by doing this pip3 --version

Comment: my python version is python 3.5.2 and for the pip3 version I got pip 8.1.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.5)

Comment: Please run this first and then run the two commands posted in the answer above. sudo apt-get install libsdl2-dev libfreetype6-dev libsdl2-mixer-dev libsdl2-image-dev libsdl2-ttf-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libportmidi-dev

Comment: I reinstalled the sd card image and connected the Pi to my internet again and i tried pip upgrading from 8.1.1, this is what i get:
`Collecting pip
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/30/db/9e38760b32e3e7f40cce46dd5fb107b8c73840df38f0046d8e6514e675a1/pip-19.2.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.4MB)
    100% |################################| 1.4MB 159kB/s 
Installing collected packages: pip
Successfully installed pip-8.1.1`

Comment: I think the image you have are missing some of the dependencies needed to run pygame. Can you please run the following and report what happens?

sudo apt-get install libsdl2-dev libfreetype6-dev libsdl2-mixer-dev libsdl2-image-dev libsdl2-ttf-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libportmidi-dev

Comment: okay i did that and i get
`Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libpng12-dev' instead of 'libpng-dev'
E: Unable to locate package libsdl2-dev
E: Unable to locate package libsdl2-mixer-dev
E: Unable to locate package libsdl2-image-dev
E: Unable to locate package libsdl2-ttf-dev
E: Unable to locate package libportmidi-dev`

Comment: would it be possible to install those dependencies directly into the image? If it has any missing, that is.

Comment: On stack exchange, it is better to edit questions and and answers rather than adding a series of comments. Comments are for helping to improve questions and answers, and are distracting, so we try to keep them to a minimum. If all of the information needed in an answer/question is contained within it, the comments can be tidied up (deleted).

Comment: Hi @MarkBooth , I'll keep that in mind for my next question but for now rather than picking out my mistakes if you could help me out here, that would be superb!

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* @MahirAhmed-Al, but please *[be nice](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/behavior)* and review our [Code of Conduct](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/conduct). I don't have the specific knowledge needed to help you, but I can suggest how you can improve your question to make it easier for people who might know the answer to help you. If you edit your question to include the additional information in these comments (what you tried, and what the results were) that *will* make it easier for people to help you with your problem.